# Managing keystores & truststore using kubernetes on gcp cloud

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am working on poc for migrating jboss rest services into spring boot services using kubernetes on google cloud platform. In linux based servers, I generally provide the path for keystores using VM arguments.
Being new to kubernetes and gcp, I am looking for help on good practice to manage keystores file. Thanks in advance!

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys#software-keystore) is what you are looking for. Are you looking for something like this [Java Keystore Best Practices](https://myarch.com/cert-book/keystore_best_practices.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand your question. Kubernetes doesn't have a concept of keystore.

If your keystore is a file you can mount as a volume to your pod or add it as a Secret in Kubernetes and mount that as a volume or environment variable to the pod

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I am looking for the way to use the truststore. Can you please share more details on how to add it as secret in kubernetes and mount to make it available for spring boot app to access. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check the Kubernetes documentation 

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/